# .exe file behaves differently when run from Unity to when open manually

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, exe, executable

I am attempting to run a .exe from Unity. The .exe runs perfectly when I open it manually by double-clicking, but from Unity, it just opens then does not work at all.

The .exe is a very basic python script (that I made into an executable) that reads a text file and then creates another one. When run from Unity the executable window says that this file does not exist/can't be found, when I know it does, and then immediately closes.

I have tried running this .exe with these methods:

```
Application.OpenURL(path);
```

And:

```
Process.Start(path);
```

The .exe works perfectly fine when I click on it and has no dependencies or anything other than that one text file.

How can I run this file from code as if it had just been clicked?

Comment: Look at the start params for the process start. Set the start directory as if you just do path/my.exe file.txt it doesn’t look in the path for that file but maybe where it thought you were which can be moved by your app too

Comment: setting StartInfo.WorkingDirectory to the path of my file's folder has now worked perfectly, is there any way I can mark this as this solution?

Comment: But I can post it as an answer, but you can also do it and get yourself the points.  Like a good person you took the hint and worked it out :) Id rather you got the points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to define the process' directory like this:

```
 Process p = new Process();
 p.StartInfo.FileName = path + "app.exe";
 p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
 p.Start();
```

with `path` being the path to the folder where the app.exe is located.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.FileName = path;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Start();
```

But I think that your path is invalid. Can you Debug.Log it and write in the comment what it is? It should be absolute path btw

Comment: The path is: C:/Users/user/Desktop/Search.exe
(with 'user' being my computer name)

Surely if the .exe does open up and run (it just doesn't work correctly) this means the path is correct?

I have also tried using Application.dataPath and Application.persistentDataPath with the same result.

Comment: yes, apologies my comment was incorrect I have edited it now. Search.exe is the name of the file.

Comment: Is your username in english?

Comment: Yes. I have got it to work now using your code and BugFinders' comment above helped to set the directory, I just don't know how to set it as the correct answer.